# Run-Time error '429': ActiveX Component Can't Create Object

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I hope you can help. I understand that this question has been asked a lot and I hope I don't get voted down. But I have tried several ways to solve this issue using online resources but I am now out of resolution options and need assistance.

As stated in the heading I am facing

> Run_Time error '429': ActiveX Component Cant't Create Object

What I can tell you is this: That I have 64bit version installed and the Macro in question works fine for me and my team based in Dublin, but other European offices who use 64 bit Version get the 429 error.

See **Pic 1** System Info. The 64bit MUST stay as installing 32Bit is not an option

I have tried all options available here [http://www.fixyourerrors.com/how-can-i-get-rid-of-runtime-error-429/](http://Solve%20429%20issues)

But no success, from the instructions in the above link.

I have checked that all the appropriate Active X controls are ticked in the Tools, Reference, area of VBA developer area/library in Excel see Pic 2

But again no affect :-(

Pic 1

[image]

Pic 2

[image]

The Code that is error is happening on is below

```
' *****************************************************************************
' Management of File to write in UT8 format
' *****************************************************************************

' This function open the file indicated to be able to write inside
Private Sub OUTFILE_OPEN(filename As String)
    Set WriteObject = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    WriteObject.Type = 2 'Specify stream type - we want To save text/string data.
    WriteObject.Charset = "utf-8" 'Specify charset For the source text data.
    WriteObject.Open 'Open the stream And write binary data To the object
    OUTFilename = filename
End Sub
```

And the line on that the 429 Error is happening on is

```
Set WriteObject = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
```

As stated I have tried to solve the issue but I am now at a dead end for a resolution. Can my code be amended or is there some trick I can do to solve the issue?

As always any and all help is greatly appreciated.

COMPLETE CODE

```
'Variables for Deduplication
Dim WB_Cust As Workbook
'File Variables
Dim DTOV_Directory As String
Dim DTOV_File As String
Dim ITOV_Directory As String
Dim ITOV_file As String

Const DELIMITER As String = "|"

' Variables for writing text into file
Dim WriteObject As Object
Dim OUTFilename As String

Dim MyWkBook As Workbook
Dim MyWkSheet As Worksheet

Dim OutputFile As String ' Output flat file name
Dim SysCode As String ' Variable for text string of system code to be filled into information system code column
Dim strFilenameOut As String ' Variable for name of file being processed. It is used for SysCode and OutputFile determination.
Dim CustAddressSave As Range


'Processing of one file. This procedure is called when only one of file types are selected
Public Sub Process_template(Directory As String, File As String, FileFlag As String)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Turns off switching of windows
    If FileFlag = "D" Then 'Variables setup for DTOV
        DTOV_Directory = Directory
        DTOV_File = File
    ElseIf FileFlag = "I" Then 'Variables setup for ITOV
        ITOV_Directory = Directory
        ITOV_file = File
    Else
        MsgBox "Unhandled Exception - Unknown files sent"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Call Process(1, FileFlag)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'Turns On switching of windows
End Sub

'Processing of two file. This procedure is called when both file types are to be processed
Public Sub Process_Templates(DTOV_Dir As String, DTOV_Fil As String, ITOV_Dir As String, ITOV_Fil As String)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Turns off switching of windows
    DTOV_Directory = DTOV_Dir
    DTOV_File = DTOV_Fil
    ITOV_Directory = ITOV_Dir
    ITOV_file = ITOV_Fil
    Call Process(2, "B")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'Turns on switching of windows
End Sub


' *****************************************************************************
' Management of File to write in UT8 format
' *****************************************************************************

' This function open the file indicated to be able to write inside
Private Sub OUTFILE_OPEN(filename As String)
    Set WriteObject = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    WriteObject.Type = 2 'Specify stream type - we want To save text/string data.
    WriteObject.Charset = "utf-8" 'Specify charset For the source text data.
    WriteObject.Open 'Open the stream And write binary data To the object
    OUTFilename = filename
End Sub

' This function closes the file
Private Sub OUTFILE_CLOSE()
    WriteObject.SaveToFile OUTFilename, 2
    WriteObject.Close ' Close the file
End Sub

' Write a string in the outfile
Private Sub OUTFILE_WRITELINE(txt As String)
    WriteObject.WriteText txt & Chr(13) & Chr(10)
    txt = ""
End Sub

' subprocedure to read TOV data into stream and call procedure to generate file
Public Sub generate_tov(i_Sheet_To_Process As String, _
                        i_OffsetShift As Integer)

    Dim sOut As String ' text to be written into file
    'Set OutputFile = "sarin"

    Sheets(i_Sheet_To_Process).Select

    Range("C2").Select
    'Parsing of system code from filename
    strFilenameOut = ActiveWorkbook.Name 'example - initial file name: EFPIA_DTOV-BE-MTOV-201503271324.xlsx
    SysCode = Left(strFilenameOut, InStrRev(strFilenameOut, "-") - 1) 'example - after LEFT cut EFPIA_ITOV-BE-MTOV
    SysCode = Right(SysCode, Len(SysCode) - InStrRev(SysCode, "-")) 'example - after RIGHT cut MTOV

    Do Until (IsError(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value) = True)
        If ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "" Then
            'end-of-file reached, hence exist the do loop
            Exit Do
        End If

        ActiveCell.Value = SysCode
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, i_OffsetShift).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheets("Template - EFPIA Customer").Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 3).Value, Sheets("Appendix").Range("N1:O103"), 2, "FALSE") & "_" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, i_OffsetShift).Value
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop

    OutputFile = Left(strFilenameOut, InStrRev(strFilenameOut, ".") - 1) & ".txt"

    If (IsError(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value) = True) Then
        MsgBox ("incorrect data in the TOV source file. Please correct and re-run the macro")
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Call generate_file
    End If


End Sub

' procedures to write stream data into file for both TOV and customer
Public Sub generate_file()

     Dim X As Integer
     Dim Y As Long
     Dim FieldValue As String
     Dim NBCol As Integer
     Dim sOut As String ' text to be written into file


     OUTFILE_OPEN (OutputFile) 'Open (setup) the output file
     'Open OutputFile For Output As #1 'Prepares new file for output
     Set MyWkBook = ActiveWorkbook
     Set MyWkSheet = ActiveSheet
     NBCol = 0

     Do While (Trim(MyWkSheet.Cells(1, NBCol + 1)) <> "")
        NBCol = NBCol + 1
     Loop
        ' Scroll all rows
     Y = 1
     Do While (Trim(MyWkSheet.Cells(Y, 4)) <> "")
        sOut = ""
        For X = 1 To NBCol
            ' here, if required, insert a convertion type function
            FieldValue = Trim(MyWkSheet.Cells(Y, X))
            FieldValue = Replace(FieldValue, "|", "/") 'Replaces pipes from input file to slashes to avoid mismatches during ETL

            If FieldValue = "0" Then FieldValue = "" 'Replaces "only zeroes" - might need redoing only for amount columns
            If InStr(MyWkSheet.Cells(1, X), "Amount") > 0 Then FieldValue = Replace(FieldValue, ",", ".")

            ' add into the string
            If X = NBCol Then
                sOut = sOut & FieldValue
            Else
                sOut = sOut & FieldValue & DELIMITER
            End If

        Next X
        Y = Y + 1
        OUTFILE_WRITELINE sOut
     Loop
    OUTFILE_CLOSE

End Sub

' read the customer data into stream
Public Sub read_customer(i_Sheet_To_Process As String, _
                         i_range As String)

    Dim CCST As Workbook ' Variable to keep reference for template Workbook that is being used for copy-paste of Customer data into virtuall Workbook

    Sheets(i_Sheet_To_Process).Select
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy
    Set CCST = ActiveWorkbook
    WB_Cust.Activate

    If i_range = "" Then
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range(CustAddressSave.Address).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Range(CustAddressSave.Address).Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
        Rows(CustAddressSave.Row).EntireRow.Delete
    Else
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Range("C2").Select
    End If

    'Call LookingUp(CCST)
    Do Until (IsError(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value) = True)

        If ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "" Then
            'end-of-file reached, hence exist the do loop
            Exit Do
        End If

        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Value, CCST.Sheets("Appendix").Range("N1:O103"), 2, "FALSE") & "_" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        ActiveCell.Value = SysCode
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop

    If (IsError(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value) = True) Then
        MsgBox ("incorrect data in the source file. Please correct and re-run the macro")
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Set CustAddressSave = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2) 'Saves position where 2nd Cust data sheet will be copied
        OutputFile = Left(Mid(strFilenameOut, 1, (InStr(strFilenameOut, "_"))) & "CUST" & Mid(strFilenameOut, (InStr(strFilenameOut, "-"))), InStrRev(strFilenameOut, ".") - 1) & ".txt"
    End If

End Sub


'Main Procedure of the module that processes the files
Private Sub Process(Loops As Integer, FileFlag As String) 'Loops - number of files (1 or 2), FileFlag - which file is to be processed (I - ITOV, D - DTOV, B - Both)

    Set WB_Cust = Workbooks.Add
    ' This virtual workbook is created only for duration of the processing. It is used to copy paste CUSTOMER data form one or both templates.

    If FileFlag = "D" Or FileFlag = "B" Then
        ' process DTOV first always
        Call Open_DTOV

        '----------------------------------------------------------
        Call generate_tov("Template - Transfer of Value", 3)
        ' if the file have data issues, then abort the procedure.
        If (IsError(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value) = True) Then
            GoTo HandleException
        End If

        '----------------------------------------------------------
        Call read_customer("Template - EFPIA Customer", "A")
        ' if the file have data issues, then abort the procedure.
        If (IsError(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value) = True) Then
            GoTo HandleException
        End If
    End If



    If FileFlag = "I" Or FileFlag = "B" Then
        Call Open_ITOV

        '----------------------------------------------------------
        Call generate_tov("Template - EFPIA iToV", 17)
        ' if the file have data issues, then abort the procedure.
        If (IsError(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value) = True) Then
            GoTo HandleException
        End If

        '----------------------------------------------------------
        If FileFlag = "B" Then
            Call read_customer("Template - EFPIA Customer", "")
        Else
            Call read_customer("Template - EFPIA Customer", "A")
        End If

        ' if the file have data issues, then abort the procedure.
        If (IsError(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value) = True) Then
            GoTo HandleException
        End If

    End If

    Call Deduplicate
    Call generate_file ' generate single customer file

    MsgBox "Export Process is completed"

HandleException:
    ' Closes the virtual workbook used for consolidation and deduplication of customers
    WB_Cust.Saved = True
    WB_Cust.Close
    ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True 'Closes Template
    ActiveWorkbook.Close (False)
    If Loops = 2 Then 'Closes second Template if two files are being processed
        ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
        ActiveWorkbook.Close (False)
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'Turns back on switching to exported excel file once it gets opened

    Exit Sub
End Sub

'Unused Procedure to reduce Customer data processing code. Does not work now.
Private Sub LookingUp(CCST As Workbook)
    Do Until (ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "")
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Value, CCST.Sheets("Appendix").Range("N1:O103"), 2, "FALSE") & "_" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        ActiveCell.Value = SysCode
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop
End Sub

'Open DTOV Template
Private Sub Open_DTOV()
    Workbooks.Open (DTOV_Directory + DTOV_File)
End Sub

'Open ITOV Template
Private Sub Open_ITOV()
    Workbooks.Open (ITOV_Directory + ITOV_file)
End Sub

'Deduplicating Customer data based on Source_Party_Identifier, which already contains source code prefix
Private Sub Deduplicate()
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=4, Header:=xlYeas
End Sub
```

Comment: At least you have a functioning and non functioning install to compare. I would start by searching the registry for the progid `ADODB.Stream` on both machines and comparing it. The ProgID in the registry in turn points at a classid which in turn points at a DLL (see here https://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/basic-understanding-com-and-related-registry). So first compare the registry setup then compare the DLL paths then the DLL versions. Then make sure the users have access to the DLL's

Comment: Also FYI, `CreateObject` is called "late binding", whereas ticking the reference in that dialog box is called "early binding". The other thing you could do is, again, comparing failing and functioning machines, try early binding "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects" (thats the ADODB part) and check that it has a class of 'stream' with the class viewer (F2).

Comment: Hi Nick. Thank you for taking the time to respond. I believe the pathways are the same. I think after further reading there is now a patch with Microsoft `"ADODB.Stream"`is now a NO NO after the latest global cyber attach which did seriously impact my company. is there a coding alternative to `"ADODB.Stream"` in VBA?

Comment: It depends what your code is doing. I've never used `stream` before. Is it writing binary objects into a database? I can't tell from your code.

Comment: Hi Nick: Yes it is writing binary objects into a database. Is there an alternative code piece that you know of to create this process?

Comment: What data type is the target column?

Comment: its all text format.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the `stream` object but that code fragment you posted doesn't do anything as far as I can tell so I'm not sure what we would need to convert. Can you look at the column that the objects are being saved into and tell me the datatype? It'll be something like `image` or `blob` or `varbinary`. Note that the code fragment you posted doesn't mention a table or a column so it's definitely incomplete.

Comment: I'm sure there's another way to do it but my google fu is failing me, and you don't have enough code there to convert

Comment: Hi Nick. I have added to code in its entirety. I avoided this previously as it is long. What this code does in a nut shell is it looks at an Excel sheet with data, then takes that data puts it into Notepad then deliminates with pipes and tehn puts it into a kind of virtual folder where it sits for a while and is pick up and sent for consumption to another database. Again thank you for the assistance it is greatly appreciated